# How do I mask the middle section of a string?

Tags: delphi, formatting

I have a string of 19 characters, if my string is :

> 123456789012345789

I want to display it like this :

> 123456*********7890

Meaning from the 7th character ot the 15th character I want to mask the characters with a `*`. What approach can I use to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to simply replace those characters by index?

Comment: What about something simple, like: `S := LeftStr(S, 6) + StringOfChar('*', Length(S) - 10) + RightStr(S, 4);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What approach? You could write a function. What obstacle do you face with that? Please [edit] your question to clarify which part of your task you're having trouble with.

Comment: Also, your string has 18 characters not 19 and the modified string has 19 and an extra 0 at the end. Details matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FUNCTION ReplaceInString(CONST Source : STRING ; StartPos,Length : Cardinal ; NewChar : CHAR): STRING;
  VAR
    P : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    Result:=Source;
    FOR P:=StartPos TO PRED(StartPos+Length) DO
      IF (P>=LOW(STRING)) AND (P<=LENGTH(Result)-(1-LOW(STRING))) THEN
        Result[P]:=NewChar
  END;
```

If you don't care for supporting 0-based strings (for mobile compilers), then you can use this instead:

```
FUNCTION ReplaceInString(CONST Source : STRING ; StartPos,Length : Cardinal ; NewChar : CHAR): STRING;
  VAR
    P : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    Result:=Source;
    FOR P:=StartPos TO PRED(StartPos+Length) DO
      IF (P>=1) AND (P<=LENGTH(Result)) THEN
        Result[P]:=NewChar
  END;
```

Use it as:

```
WRITELN(ReplaceInString('123456789012345789',7,9,'*'))
```